# Purpose of capacitors near the input of DC/DC boost converter

Tags: capacitor, pcb, dc-dc-converter, converter, buck-boost

[image]

I recently bought this DC to DC boost converter (input from top; output from bottom). It has all the parts as a usual boost converter topology suggests: a mosfet, a diode, an inductor, and capacitors near the output.

I am wondering what are the purposes of the capacitors near the input. Is it for a soft startup?

Answer (score 3):

No. These capacitors are the sources of AC current to the converter input. The interconnecting wires and the supply that feeds the converter input usually have impedances orders of magnitude larger than what the converter needs to reach rated performance (regulation, efficiency, control loop stability at the very least).

> It has all the parts as a usual boost converter topology suggests

Those are conceptual models, and I claim they are poor ones, as input capacitors aren't something you can just forget to mention, as they form the part of the primary current loop in the converter. You're using some misleading/poor sources to look these things up.

Comment: They also might be there to damp the input overshoot resulting from connecting the board up with long leads.  See: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an88f.pdf

Comment: @vir It gets tricky. When those capacitors are too good, they generate amazing transients as they resonate with the cable inductance. But in most cases, electrolytics of the volume shown aren't too bad in this respect. Things get hairy if you'd replace the input electrolytics with an array of paralleled ceramics or tantalums and let the thing loose on the end user. Attaching such loads under power generates impressive transients that tend to kill parts when repeated often enough.